# How can I display the function that returns enum type data in this program

Tags: c++, enums

I have implemented Date Class that aims to display different date formats. I have a problem at `d1.Display_version3();`  it can not return enum data correctly. How can I change my code? Here is my code:

```
  //Decleration of Class Date.

#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
class Date{

    private:

        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        enum Month {
            January, February, March, April, May, June,
            July, August,September,October, November, December
        };
        Month m;
        int checkdate(int);

    public:
        /*Overloading Constructors*/
        Date(int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900);//constructor 1
        Date(int = 1, Month = January, int = 1900);//constructor 2
        /*Read functions*/
        int read_date() const;
        int read_month() const;
        int read_year() const;
        Month read_month_ex() const;
        /*Display Functions*/
        void Display_version1() const;//mm/dd/yy
        void Display_version2() const;//dd.mm.YYYY
        void Display_version3() const;//May 14,1992
};
#endif

/*Decleration of the Class Members*/

#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "date.h"

Date::Date(int dd, int mm, int yy){

    month = (mm>0 && mm<12) ? mm : 1;//ensure that month is valid
    year = yy;
    day=checkdate(dd);

}
Date::Date(int dd, Month mm, int yy){

    m = (mm>January && mm<December) ? mm : January;//ensure that month is valid
    year = yy;
    day = checkdate(dd);

}
int Date::checkdate(int dd){

    static const int daysinamonth[13] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if (dd>0 && dd <= daysinamonth[month]);
    return dd;
    if (month==2 && dd==29 &&(year%400==0 || (year%4==0 && year%100!=0)));
    return dd;
    return 1;//if it is not valid date.
}
int Date::read_date() const{
    return day;
};
int Date::read_month() const{
    return month;
};
int Date::read_year() const{
    return year;
};
Date::Month Date::read_month_ex() const{
    return m;
};
void Date::Display_version1() const{

    cout << read_month() << "." << read_date() << "." << (read_year()-1900) << endl;

};//mm/dd/yy
void Date::Display_version2() const{

    cout << read_date() << "." << read_month() << "." << read_year() << endl;

};//dd.mm.YYYY
void Date::Display_version3() const{


    cout << read_month_ex() <<" "<< read_date() << "," << read_year() << endl;

};//May 14,1992
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include"date.h"

int main(){

    Date d1(5, 10, 1990);

    d1.Display_version1();//mm/dd/yy
    d1.Display_version2();//dd.mm.YYYY
    d1.Display_version3();//display as May 14,1992, problem is here!!!

    while (1);
}
```

Comment: You don't display functions (they are mostly known at compile time, and don't really & fully exist at runtime....)

Comment: To display some `enum` value, you have to make a function displaying it (consider using a `switch`, or a constant static or global array of constant strings...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type

```
enum Month {
    January, February, March, April, May, June,
    July, August,September,October, November, December
};
```

the compiler does not actually put strings like "February" anywhere in your program (except maybe in a separate debug data section).  All it does is learn that `Date::Month` is a new type, and the enumerators like `Date::February` are values of that type, represented by numbers.  Since you let it choose the numbers, it uses `January = 0, February = 1,` ... `December = 11`.  As far as the running code is concerned, those values are pretty much just numbers, and it has no clue what they were called, just like `int x` is a region of storage and the program has no clue its name was `x`.

So you'll have to provide the strings somewhere yourself.  Probably the simplest way here, since the numeric values are `0` to `11` in order, is with an array:

```
class Date {
public:
    const char* read_month_ex() const;
// ...
private:
    static char const* const month_names[12];
};

char const* const Date::month_names[12] = {
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

const char* Date::read_month_ex() const {
    return month_names[m];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type from `enum` to `const char*`:

```
const char* Date::read_month_ex() const
{
    static const char* months[] = {"JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"};
    return months[m];
};
```